# Picasso-SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null (Android)

Tags: android, picasso

When I try to parse a picture from a url i've got this information:
**SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null**  I am using Picasso library.
Below is my Json structure and onBindViewHolder .

```
"flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/col.svg",
"regionalBlocs": [{
    "acronym": "PA",
    "name": "Pacific Alliance",
    "otherAcronyms": [],
    "otherNames": ["Alianza del Pacífico"]
}, {
```

**onBindViewHolde**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.country_name.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
    holder.country_region.setText(dataList.get(position).getRegion());
    holder.country_topleveldomain.setText(dataList.get(position).getTopLevelDomain().toString());
    holder.country_nativename.setText(dataList.get(position).getNativeName());
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(dataList.get(position).getFlag())
    .into(holder.imageView);


}
```

Comment: "https://restcountries.eu/data/col.svg" i think you have to check it with .png or .jpeg may be .svg not support by picasso

Comment: Ok , i understand:(

Comment: Could you tell me,  how can i parse svg format?